# Managing subscription of push notification on client and server sides

Tags: javascript, push-notification, notifications, workbox

I erase all my previous questions on how to use the code give into the documentation of [workbox push notification](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications) to show you the solution I found more clearly.

before to show you the code, I will explain that I took long time to understand. You use normaly three files that work with service worker. In my case `server.js`, `index.js` and `sw.js`. When the browser get all the files it need to display your site, I also get the index.js file. This file start the service worker with `navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')`. Then, it test if the user has already accepted to receive notification. At the end, it check if subscription exist or not and manage its.
The subscription part is very important and difficult to manage. With `swRegistration.pushManager.subscribe()` we will get an `sub` object. This object contains the *endpoint*, the *auth* and the *p256th*. Those informations are very important and we need to send to our server to store it into our database. the `fetch()` element do it. By this way, we will be able to send a notification to our tagerted user in the futur.

The last thing you need to know and how to create private and public Vapid keys. To generate it, display into your terminal the *console.log* that are below my `privateVapidKey` variable inside *server.js*. Then copy-paste both results into variable as I did server.js and alse copy-paste publicsVapidKey into *index.js* file.

**server.js :**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var webPush = require('web-push');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');    

https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('key_localhost2.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert_localhost2.pem'),
  passphrase: 'localhost',
}, app).listen(8080);

//*****************************************************************
//-------------------------- TEMPLATES --------------------------
//*****************************************************************
//moteur de modèles ou de templates
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//*****************************************************************
//-------------------------- MIDDLEWARE --------------------------
//*****************************************************************    
app
  .use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
  .use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/js'))
  .use(bodyParser.json());

//*****************************************************************
//--------------------------- ROUTES ------------------------------
//*****************************************************************   
app.get('/', function (request, response) {
  response.render('./pages/index.ejs');
});

var publicVapidKey = "BKwLqQWMQpLfSNGb-VXCsAPE1H5o7Oh3VxDiEIqWWOm2OdAoFPqr9K9WI7dKKtjYYHLTKm7tjJO04091pDXZiJs"
var privateVapidKey = "483sZs2cZUxSQegGKKOZXLl_b7_ywBF_qJO77gXFsHE"
//console.log('Publics keys : ' + vapidKeys.publicKey)
//console.log('Private key : ' + vapidKeys.privateKey)

webPush.setVapidDetails(
  'mailto:localhost:8080',
  publicVapidKey,
  privateVapidKey
);

var pushSubscription; 

app.post('/subscription_push_notification', function (req, resp) {
  pushSubscription = req.body;
  console.log(pushSubscription)

  //I'm able to save this information into my database
  endpointVal = req.body.endpoint;
  authVal = req.body.keys.auth;
  p256dhVal = req.body.keys.p256dh;

  setTimeout(function () {

    if (endpointVal) {

      var payload = 'Here is a payload!';

      webPush.sendNotification(
        pushSubscription,
        payload
      ).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
  }, 2000)

  resp.json({});
});
```

**index.js :**

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {

    //*********************************************************
    // Start SW, permission notification, register subscribe
    //*********************************************************
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {

        //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        //Register Service worker
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
            .then(function (swRegistration) {

                //Ask to notification permission
                displayNotification();

                var publicVapidKey = "BKwLqQWMQpLfSNGb-VXCsAPE1H5o7Oh3VxDiEIqWWOm2OdAoFPqr9K9WI7dKKtjYYHLTKm7tjJO04091pDXZiJs";
                var applicationServerKey = urlBase64ToUint8Array(publicVapidKey);

                //Manage push notifiaction
                swRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription().then(function (sub) {
                    if (sub === null) {
                        // Update UI to ask user to register for Push
                        console.log('Not subscribed to push service!');

                        swRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({
                            userVisibleOnly: true,
                            applicationServerKey: applicationServerKey
                        }).then(function (sub) {
                            // We have a subscription, update the database
                            console.log('Endpoint URL: ', sub.endpoint);
                            fetch('/subscription_push_notification', {
                                method: 'POST',
                                body : JSON.stringify(sub),
                                headers: {
                                    'content-type':'application/json'
                                }
                            });
                        }).catch(function (e) {

                            if (Notification.permission === 'denied') {
                                console.warn('Permission for notifications was denied');
                            } else {
                                console.error('Unable to subscribe to push', e);
                            }
                        });

                    } else {
                        // We have a subscription, update the database
                        console.log('Subscription object: ', sub);
                        fetch('/subscription_push_notification', {
                            method: 'POST',
                            body : JSON.stringify(sub),
                            headers: {
                                'content-type':'application/json'
                            }
                        });

                    }
                });
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('Service Worker registration failed: ', err);

            })

    }


    //*********************************************************
    // Function ask to notification permission
    //*********************************************************
    function displayNotification() {

        if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
            //Mean, the notification is accepted.
            console.log('Notification accepted...');

        } else if (Notification.permission === "blocked" || Notification.permission === "denied") {
            // the user has previously denied notification. Can't reprompt.
            console.log('Notification blocked...');

        } else {
            // show a prompt to the user
            console.log('Prompt to accept notification');

            Notification.requestPermission();
        }
    }


    //*********************************************************
    // Transform public Vapid key
    //*********************************************************
    function urlBase64ToUint8Array(base64String) {
        const padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
        const base64 = (base64String + padding)
            .replace(/\-/g, '+')
            .replace(/_/g, '/');

        const rawData = window.atob(base64);
        const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);

        for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
            outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        return outputArray;
    }

});
```

**sw.js :**

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.4.1/workbox-sw.js');

if (workbox) {
  console.log(`Yay! Workbox is loaded `);
} else {
  console.log(`Boo! Workbox didn't load `);
}


//*********************************************************
// Save file from site to work in offline mode
//*********************************************************
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([
  { url: '/', revision: '383676' },
  { url: '/static/css/style.css', revision: '383677' },
  { url: '/static/js/index.js', revision: '383678' },
]);

//*********************************************************
// The notification click event
//*********************************************************
//Inform when the notification close/hide from the window 
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (e) {
  console.log('notification was clicked')
  var notification = e.notification;
  var action = e.action;

  if (action === 'close') {
    notification.close();
  } else {
    clients.openWindow('https://www.google.fr');
  };
});


//*********************************************************
// Handling the push event in the service worker
//*********************************************************
self.addEventListener('push', function (e) {
  console.log('Hi man !!!')

  var options = {
    body: e.data.text(),
    icon: '/static/img/logo_menu.png',
    vibrate: [100, 50, 100],
    data: {
      dateOfArrival: Date.now(),
      primaryKey: '2'
    },
  };
  e.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification('Hello world!', options)
  );
});
```

Comment: Not clear to me why in index.js, if you have a subscription already, then you have to update it in your database. Shouldn't stay the same?